# auth_token for slack integration

Tags: slack, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-monitoring

I would like to setup alerting using slack in GCP using Terraform.

My code is:

```
resource "google_monitoring_notification_channel" "slack" {
  display_name = "Prod Slack Alerts"
  type         = "slack"
  labels = {
    "channel_name" = "#alert-channel"
  }
  sensitive_labels {
    auth_token = "one"
  }
}
```

But the question is how do I get the `auth_token` ? I looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54884815) but this solution is outdated and does not work. Plus there is no documentation on this. I already have the Google Cloud Monitoring app integrated into my organization's slack.

Comment: The post you provided worked on my end. Are you getting any error when following it? With regards to the documentation for it, you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-notifications/configure-slack).

Comment: Hey @jeunii did you figure this out? I can't figure out how or where to get the slack auth_token either.

Comment: @DavidBrown See my answer

Answer (score 6):

Alright so I found the way to do it. Its a bit hacky but it did the job for me !

I first went ahead and created the Slack integration manually using the UI. Click on "EDIT NOTIFICATION CHANNEL". Once the new slack integration has been completed, I ran the following `gcloud` command:

```
gcloud alpha monitoring channels list --project <PROJECT>
```

This will return

```
...
displayName: Prod Slack Alerts
enabled: true
labels:
  auth_token: '****************************************************GdjG'
  channel_name: '#slack_channel'
name: projects/<PROJECCT>/notificationChannels/<CHANNEL-ID>
type: slack
...
```

This gives you an idea that it ends with `GdjG`. Your token can end differently. You will need to find this using you web browser's Inspector. I will be using `GdjG` as an example.

Now go back and create the slack notification manually again but this time, open the Web browser's Inspector and search for `GdjG`. Once you are done with all the flow you should see something like this:

[image]

So look for URLs like

```
Request URL: https://slack.com/api/auth.test?token=
:path: /api/auth.test?token=
```

You can now go ahead and create your slack channel using Terraform by using the token. In my experience, the token does not change if you are trying to integrate with the same slack organization.

Comment: this seems awfully hacky but I'm glad you figured it out. I assume the token is a JWT token, so did you check the expire time on it?

Comment: After 1.5 years, this is still a valid answer.